# Use Like Sql syntax for All columns

Tags: php, sql, database, search, sql-like

i want to do this

```
$this->connection->query("SELECT * FROM database WHERE all_columns LIKE '%word%' ");
```

how can i do this ?

Comment: what u have tried?

Comment: Nope, one LIKE per column is needed, for each table...

Comment: well, aren't you already doing this?

Comment: Don't you know where you store your data?

Comment: i have tried to search about this. but i think it's possible to do this without defined where colum1 like %word% or column2 like %word% or column3 like %word%

Comment: `but i think it's possible to do this without defined where colum1 like %word% ....`. No it's not possible